# Passing Object ID to URL Django Python

Tags: python, django

I am very new to Django so it is hard for me to understand what information is most relevant to try and find the answer to my question.

I followed a tutorial to learn Django. The class creates a shopping cart. I have a problem where I can not add items to the shopping cart or remove them. The main thing that looks suspicious to me is that in the database when I look at a cart there is a drop down to select book but instead of the name of the book it says `Book Object`. I believe this is the problem but I am not sure how to troubleshoot it.
[image]

I am starting to think maybe this problem is the difference in versions. The tutorial is using a later version. I am using

python 2.7.10
django 1.9.4

I assume this comes down to my models and my view

URL to add to cart and remove

```
url(r'^add/(\d+)', views.add_to_cart, name='add_to_cart'),  
url(r'^remove/(\d+)', views.remove_from_cart, name='remove_from_cart'),
```

Here is the model for Cart and BookOrder

```
   from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self): 
        return "%s, %s" % (self.last_name, self.first_name)


def cover_upload_path(instance,filename):
    return '/'.join(['books',str(instance.id),filename])


class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    description = models.TextField()
    publish_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=8)
    stock = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    cover_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=cover_upload_path, default='books/empty_cover.jpg')

class Review(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    publish_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    text = models.TextField()
    latitude= models.FloatField(max_length=20, default="37.41920")
    longitude= models.FloatField(max_length=20, default="122.8574")

class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    order_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    payment_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    payment_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

    def add_to_cart(self, book_id):
        book = Book.objects.get(pk=book_id)
        try:
            preexisting_order = BookOrder.objects.get(book=book, cart=self)
            preexisting_order.quantity += 1
            preexisting_order.save()
        except BookOrder.DoesNotExist:
            new_order = BookOrder.objects.create(
                book=book,
                cart=self,
                quantity=1
                )
            new_order.save()

    def remove_from_cart(self, book_id):
        book = Book.objects.get(pk=book_id)
        try:
            preexisting_order = BookOrder.objects.get(book=book, cart=self)
            if preexisting_order.quantity > 1:
                preexisting_order.quantity -= 1
                preexisting_order.save()
            else:
                preexisting_order.delete()
        except BookOrder.DoesNotExist:
            pass


class BookOrder(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

And here is the view for adding and removing from cart.

```
def add_to_cart(request,book_id):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            try:
                book = Book.objects.get(pk=book_id)
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                pass
            else :
                try:
                    cart = Cart.objects.get(user = request.user, active = True)
                except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                    cart = Cart.objects.create(user = request.user)
                    cart.save()
                    cart.add_to_cart(book_id)
                    return redirect('cart')
                else:
                    return redirect('index')


def remove_from_cart(request, book_id):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        try:
            book = Book.objects.get(pk = book_id)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            pass 
        else:
            cart = Cart.objects.get(user = request.user, active = True)
            cart.remove_from_cart(book_id)
        return redirect('cart')
    else:
        return redirect('index')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For being able to see object names instead of seeing `Model object`, you need to define `__unicode__` method in your model.

For your cart model:

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    ...
    [fields]
    ...

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s's cart" % self.user.username
```

By defining this, you'll be able to see "username's cart"

For BookOrder Model

```
class BookOrder(models.Model):

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.book.name or self.book.title
```

By defining this, you'll be able to see the book name like "My Book name".

Comment: I had a unicode method in my model. I updated the question with my full model to show you.

Comment: You have `__unicode__` method only in your `Author` model, you need to define it on every model.

Comment: ahh ok thank you. Just the same thing I have? Copy it each time to each method? Better question. is sel.lastname the value I am getting? So Ig I want book ID i need self.book_id

Comment: Yes exactly! You can access foreignkey fields too.

Comment: Ok great thank you. Did this change recently because it does not do this in the tutorial. Could this be do to versions? I really want to master this.

Comment: No, it is not a recent change. It was there in the previous versions too.

Comment: @wuno can u share the link for tutorial ...I also want to learn django

Comment: https://www.udemy.com/learn-python-django-from-scratch/learn/v4/overview
its decent man. But if you go back and read the code it starts to make sense. Feel free to check my github if you need the source.

Answer (score 1):

Add `__str__()` or `__unicode__()` method in your models. This method is called whenever string representation of an object is required e.g. as you seeing while displaying as a choice in dropdown menu.

You can return any string as it suits your.

Sample:

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    ...
    def __str__(self,):
        return str(self.id)
        #OR
        return str(self.user)+str(self.id)
```

Comment: I had a unicode method in my model. I updated the question with my full model to show you.

Comment: @wuno, You may want to decorate your class for support for unicode with python2, something changed in django 1.9. Also, try adding `__str__` method as well, ref https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#str

Comment: Great thank you man. Can you explain what __str__ is going vs just unicode? the unicode works for the author name so I assume I don't need str but I am about to find out. But for future reference why would you suggest using that here?

Comment: `__str__` for python3.